# Unity WebGL - accessing StreamingAssets folder from build uploaded in LMS /Server

Tags: unity-game-engine, scorm, unity-webgl

I couldn't access the files StreamingAssets folder from WebGL build which is uploaded in LMS server, I kept those files in StreamingAssets folder to update it for future use. Followed the instruction given in unity manual, working fine in editor, but with direct build run and in LMS its not working.

http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Application-streamingAssetsPath.html

Posted in forums, they ask to follow the manual, but its not working. Please find the script attached here for more details. Check the coroutine function named ' userDetailsXmlPath ' which called at start of the game.

```
public string filePath = Application.streamingAssetsPath + "/UserDetails.xml";
public string result = "";

IEnumerator userDetailsXmlPath() 
{
    print (filePath);

    if (filePath.Contains ("://") || filePath.Contains (":///")) {
        WWW www = new WWW (filePath);
        yield return www;
        result = www.text;

        print (result);
        FetchUserDetails ();
    } else {
        result = File.ReadAllText (filePath);

        print (result);
        FetchUserDetails ();
    }
}

public void FetchUserDetails()
{
    XmlDocument userXml1 = new XmlDocument ();
//  userXml1.Load(Application.streamingAssetsPath + "/UserDetails.xml");
//  userXml1.Load(Application.dataPath + "js/UserDetails 1.xml");
//  userXml1.LoadXml(userXml.text);

    userXml1.LoadXml(result);


    XmlNodeList userList = userXml1.GetElementsByTagName ("user");

    foreach(XmlNode userValue in userList)
    {
        XmlNodeList userContent = userValue.ChildNodes;
        objUser = new Dictionary<string, string>();

        foreach(XmlNode value in userContent)
        {
            objUser.Add (value.Name, value.InnerText);
        }

        userFullDetails.Add (objUser);

        userCountInXml = userList.Count;

        userId = new string[userList.Count];
        questionSetOfUser = new string[userList.Count];
    }

    AssignUserXmlValuesToArray ();
}
```

Please guild me to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Access StreamingAssets path folder using WWW class https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Application-streamingAssetsPath.html

```html
public string filePath = Application.streamingAssetsPath + "/UserDetails.xml";
         public string result = "";
   
   void Awake () 
   { 
   filePath = Application.streamingAssetsPath + "/UserDetails.xml"; 
   }
   
   void Start () 
   { 
   StartCoroutine(userDetailsXmlPath() );
   }
   
         IEnumerator userDetailsXmlPath() 
         {
             print (filePath);
     
             if (filePath.Contains ("://") || filePath.Contains (":///")) {
                 WWW www = new WWW (filePath);
                 yield return www;
                 result = www.text;
     
                 print (result);
                 FetchUserDetails ();
             } else {
                 result = File.ReadAllText (filePath);
     
                 print (result);
                 FetchUserDetails ();
             }
         }
     
         public void FetchUserDetails()
         {
             XmlDocument userXml1 = new XmlDocument ();
     
             userXml1.LoadXml(result);
     
     
             XmlNodeList userList = userXml1.GetElementsByTagName ("user");
     
             foreach(XmlNode userValue in userList)
             {
                 XmlNodeList userContent = userValue.ChildNodes;
                 objUser = new Dictionary<string, string>();
     
                 foreach(XmlNode value in userContent)
                 {
                     objUser.Add (value.Name, value.InnerText);
                 }
     
                 userFullDetails.Add (objUser);
     
                 userCountInXml = userList.Count;
     
                 userId = new string[userList.Count];
                 questionSetOfUser = new string[userList.Count];
             }
     
             AssignUserXmlValuesToArray ();
         }
```